# play framework dependecies

Tags: playframework

I am frequently getting below error when I do the  'play dependencies'.

I am using play 1.2.2  and morphia 1.2.3d    It is able to resolve morphia dependency, but throwing below error.

```
~
~ *****************************************************************************
~ WARNING: These dependencies are missing, your application may not work properl
y (use --verbose for details),
~
~       play->play 1.2
~ *****************************************************************************
~
~ Some dependencies are still missing.
~
```

When I add the line 'play->play 1.2' to conf/dependencies.yml file, it shows another error :

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
            module not found: play#play;1.2

    ==== playCore: tried

      E:\My_Pro\play_framewrk\play-1.2.2/framework/dependencies.yml

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            :: play#play;1.2: not found

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
            playCore: unacceptable revision => was=1.2.2 required=1.2
```

Does this mean that , the higher versions of PLAY not downward compatible ?

Comment: Could you add the content of your dependencies file.

Answer (score 1):

Don't specify which version of play to use :

Your dependencies.yml :

```
# Application dependencies

require:
    - play
    - morphia 1.2.3d
```

Answer (score 0):

As almost every application, Play is using Semantic Versioning syntax for their version number. Checkout the [SemVer website](http://semver.org/) for more information.

So an upgrade from 1.2 to 1.2.2 should not be dangerous. It is simply displaying a message saying that since the moduel was expplicitly tested for version 1.2 and no versions above. Meaning issues **could** appear.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.playframework.org/modules/morphia-1.2.5a/start
gives this:

```
require:
    - play -> morphia [1.2.4,)
```

I have no idea what this wonky syntax does, other than that it works.

I wish there were an explanation somewhere of what the syntax is for the dependencies.yml file.  I found that when I just used 1.2.4 without the `[,)` it didn't work.